# How to display posts from a certain community?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While learning Ruby on rails, I'm trying to find a way to display posts inside communities, but I only managed to display the first post created inside the community

This is what I have so far

communities_controller.rb:

```
def show 
    if params[:id]
        @posts = Post.where("id = ?", params[:id])
     else
        @posts = Post.all
     end 
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <%= link_to  post.title, community_post_path(@community, post) %>
    <%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :communities do
    resources :posts
end
```

EDIT: Upon closer inspection I found that it will also display a post in community in which it doesn't belong if that community has no posts of it's own

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! How many posts do you have for a particular community, also it would be great if you can provide a few more information? Best if you share your github repository URL here.

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: @RishiPithadiya Thank you for the welcome, here is the repo

https://github.com/ifiala/reddit-klon

Comment: @ficalino - I added my answer here. Have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416706/3744443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove [this line](https://github.com/ifiala/reddit-klon/blob/master/app/models/post.rb#L6) from your code, so your Post model will look like following -

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :community

  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :account_id, :community_id
end
```

Add above removed line in [this file](https://github.com/ifiala/reddit-klon/blob/master/app/models/community.rb#L5), so Community model will look like follow -

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  validates_presence_of :url, :name, :rules 

  has_many :posts
end
```

Now use following code for show method -

```
def show
  @posts = @community.posts
end
```

It'll solve the issue. Please let me know if you get any errors. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

When you click a specific community link, the `params[:id]` contains the id of that community. So you should use that id parameter for `Community` model not the `Post`. After finding that community record from DB you can get the posts like this:

```rb
def show
  @community = Community.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @community.posts
end
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error saying

 NoMethodError in CommunitiesController#show
undefined method `posts' for #<Community:0x00007f873c99f870>

Comment: That error occurs because you have no defined relation named `posts` between `Community` and `Post` model

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the `communities_controller`, you should look for a community:

#### communities_controller.rb

```
def show
  @community = Community.find(params[:id]
end
```

Once you have that, you can iterate through your `@community.posts` in the show view:

#### communities/show.html.erb

```
<% @community.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to  post.title, community_post_path(@community, post) %>
  <%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %>
<% end %>
```

You can also find the posts in the `communities_controller` and then use those posts in the view:

#### communities_controller

```
def show
  @community = Community.find(params[:id]
  @posts     = @community.posts
end
```

#### communities/show.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to  post.title, community_post_path(@community, post) %>
  <%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %>
<% end %>
```

Also, if your community has no posts, you'll probably get an error page in your browser. You can use something like this to save you from that error:

```
<% if @community.posts.any? %>
  <% @community.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to  post.title, community_post_path(@community, post) %>
    <%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no posts for this community.</p>
<% end %>
```

You should also make sure you have `community_id` in your posts table and you have your associations setup properly:

#### community.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

#### post.rb

```
belongs_to :community
```